# Play videon on Android custom activity

Tags: android, video, youtube, playing

I want to play video in my application(ex::::my `Webview`) means I don't want to play the video in Youtube. 
This is my code:

```
myWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
myWebview.loadUrl("www.youtube.com/embed/bIPcobKMB94");
```

video is playing in Youtube by leaving the application.
If any one have the solution for this please give me the reply.

-rajani